# Shod wee bernynate tae [syntex] tg?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [syntex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntex) tag has 12 questions, but 11 of them are not about the now [unmaintained Rust library by this name](https://crates.io/crates/syntex/0.48.0) (thanks @RyanM for digging that up).

There is no tag description or wiki page.

Following the [burnination checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) for this tag:

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

Clearly not, as it mostly attracts typos. To the extent that this was well-defined in the first place, the scope seems to be quite obscure even for the intended target audience (Rust programmers familiar with a defunct library).

> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

I would argue no; [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) is (albeit with very low value) but this is a typo of that low-value tag, and as such pretty much meaningless.

(Perhaps it should be nominated as a synonym for [syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/syntax) after burnination, though?)

> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

No, not the way it is used now. See previous item.

> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Clearly not, as the people who typed it actually meant something else.

I can't pretend to have "authoritative knowledge" of this tag, and so I suppose this is not eligible for the abbreviated burnination process.

Comment: Since most questions there use the tag because of a typo (meant as "syntax"), they are mostly delete-worthy as they are about syntax errors and are typos themselves. Then we are basically left with the one question about the library. Since the mis-use is greater than the intended purpose - I say just burn. That one question will be fine without it...

Comment: I agree: just burn the tag, no need to make it a synonym of [tag:syntax] because once it's gone, it won't appear as a suggested tag when people write questions anyway. There is no need for us to have synonyms for misspellings of tag names.

Comment: With just 12 questions, it is a simple matter of editing for anyone suitably privileged.

Comment: Part of the goal of burninations (even such small ones) is to go over the questions of the tag and use the chance for a clean-up. Simply removing the tag from those questions will leave off-topic, delete-worthy questions floating around. Instead we should go over the tag and close/delete deserving questions and only then retag the leftovers

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The last paragraph tries to cover this ground. The burnination FAQ I link to is adamant that I should seek consensus here before I start doing anything about the mess I have identified, though it does seem to be less authoritative than it pretends to be; [the SE meta it quotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/) seems to be more nuanced and in better harmony with actual practice - but it too urges to start any process with a coordination discussion.

Comment: dat title tho..

Comment: That is not a common misspelling or typo. I didn't [have it](https://pmortensen.eu/EditOverflow/_Wordlist/EditOverflowList_latest.html#syntax) (until today) - though there is a very, very long tail.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I can agree with the post here. The tag looks like a typo of syntax. My proposal would be to just get rid of the tag completely.

Originally I thought of replacing the tag with [rust-syntex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rust-syntex) for the lone question about the syntex library, but that would be ambiguous as well and might confuse users into thinking that it is a tag for "rust syntax". (This is exactly why we need to use meaningful names for our libraries.)

Comment: If there needs to be a tag for this library, then `rust-syntex-library` seems the safest. But with only one real question about it, especially if the library is now defunct, it seems no tag should be needed.